# nginx reverse proxy folder

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to access a server behind another with a reverse proxy. The "main" server is behind mydomain.com and I would like to access the second one by using mydomain.com/test. For the moment just mydomain.com/test works.

But if I try to access mydomain.com/test/myfiles, I'm redirected to mydomain.com/myfiles which doesn't exist because this url target the "main" server, so 404 not found appears. I tried multiple thing with proxy_redirect, rewrite but nothing worked.

```
server {
    listen   80;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    root /path/to/content;
    server_name localhost mydomain.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404; #/index.html;
    }

    location /test/ {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.202/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

`curl -I "http://192.168.1.202" -H "Host: mydomain.com"` on the main server gives :

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.2.1
Date: Sun, 02 Nov 2014 15:02:56 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 184
Location: example.com/myfiles
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: What's the output of `curl -I "http://192.168.1.202/myfiles" -H "Host: mydomain.com"` ?

Comment: This command executed from the main server I get : HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.2.1
Date: Sun, 02 Nov 2014 15:02:56 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 184
Location: http://example.com/myfiles/
Connection: keep-alive

Comment: Why is it `Server: nginx` ? Do you have nginx behind nginx ? Anyway , see my answer.

Comment: Yes I have nginx behind nginx, why ?

Comment: Just asking, seems weird.

Comment: Why it is weird ? Is it a bad thing ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18347/discussion-between-p1rox-and-xavier-lucas).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that when you use a trailing slash with the `proxy_pass` directive, the default behaviour for `proxy_redirect` is that the following :

```
location /test/ {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.202/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

Is the same as :

```
location /test/ {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.202/;
    proxy_redirect http://192.168.1.202/ /test/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

So given the curl output, you must set this up :

```
location /test/ {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.202/;
    proxy_redirect http://$host/ /test/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

Comment: Accessing example.com/myfiles/ displays my index.php page but example.com/myfiles/index.php displays "File not found". Weird

Comment: @p1rox That's because the index directive makes an internal redirect to the index file so it falls in the php location everytime.